# What is the potentiation operation?

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain what the potentiation operation is? I could not find a clear explanation when searching online.

Comment: Please provide more information. What sort of course are you taking? Is there a specific problem you're working on? What have you done so far?

Comment: I met the term in a [fun maths problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1479.pdf) and as it turns out it does just mean exponentiation. Sorry for being vague but at the time the term had me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentiation is usually raising something to a power, e.g. if $x$ is potentiated by $y$ then you have $x^y$.

But this is context dependent as @mephistolotl commented (*potential functions* crop up a lot and potentiation could refer to using one of them).

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed raising something to a power. As a follow-up, is there a difference between exponentiation and potentiation or is the latter just an older term?

Comment: As far as I know potentiation is just the wrong term.  Mathematically it's exponentiation and always has been.  The paper you linked to looks to have been written by a non-native-speaker of English so it could be a translation error.  But all the dictionaries I can easily check don't list potentiation as having a mathematical meaning, they just note it's from the Latin *potentia* meaning *power*.